# Dynamic Page/Post on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic-content

I'm a wordpress newbie trying to add dynamic posts and pages through get requests.
Is there a better way than suggested in http://www.blogseye.com/2010/05/creating-fake-wordpress-posts-on-the-fly?
Maybe one that doesn't need to check if the content exists in the database?

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that looks like the most straightforward way to do what you want.  And it doesn't check to see if the content exists in the database - it's just triggered when WordPress can't find a resource at a given permalink.